# Run function only the first time the user types in form input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-watch

This should be straight forward but haven't found a solution yet.

I have an `input` in a `form`. I want to detect when a user has interacted with the input and run a javascript function **once** if they have.

I have been thinking of using a `$watch` to detect if the `input` element has the class `ng-dirty` and if it has, run js function and unbind the watch.

Is there a better way? It would be great if you could provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple directive that should do what you're looking for.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar was called!');
    $scope.barWasCalled = true;
  };
})
.directive('once', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      fn: '&once'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
      // add a listener and save the index for removal
      var idx = ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
        // user typed, run the function
        $scope.fn();
        // remove the listener
        ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.splice(idx, 1);
      }) - 1;
    }
  };
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo" once="bar()" placeholder="type something...">
  <div ng-show="barWasCalled">Bar was called!</div>
</div>
```

`$viewChangeListener` offers just a touch better performance than a `$watch`, though it is nominal anyway.

Remember to put any kind of DOM related behaviors such as this into directives. That keeps things light and neat.

Answer (score 2):

$watch is not for that. $watch really does not watch if you change something from outside of the angular context.

Either you can use ng-change event for interactive with input OR use raw javascript onChange using a custom directive and invoke scope.$digest finally

Easy solution is to use ng-change:

```
<input type="text" name="test" ng-change="doChanges()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $watchCollection on a directive.  It returns a de-registration function that you can call to unbind the watch on the form.  The benefit of doing it this way is that it watches the form, not the model or any specific input.  This way, as soon as any input on the form is modified, the callback function of the $watchCollection is executed and removed.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

  angular.module('app')
    .directive('mainForm', mainForm);

  mainForm.$inject = ['$log'];

  function mainForm($log) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        myForm: "=ngForm"
      },
      link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      var undoWatch = scope.$watchCollection('myForm', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        //check if the form is dirty
        if (newVal.$dirty) {
          alert("do this one time!");
          //unbind the function so we don't do it again
          undoWatch();
        }
      });
    }

  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <h1>Do Action Once Example</h1>
  <div ng-form="example" main-form novalidate>
    <p> Use any input on the page to alert the user one time.</p>
    <input ng-model="inputVal" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <input ng-model="anotherInputVal" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <p>{{ inputVal }}</p>
</body>

</html>
```